# Invalid keys -> ProfileLevel in a AVCaptureVideoDataOutput (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, core-graphics, core-media

I'm adding keys to my `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`. when adding the key `AVVideoProfileLevelKey` the system throws me ->

> Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property
>   on (NSWindow): *** +[AVVideoOutputSettings
>   videoOutputSettingsWithVideoSettingsDictionary:] Output settings
>   dictionary contains one or more invalid keys: ProfileLevel

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var videoCaptureOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
videoCaptureOutput.videoSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
                                        AVVideoWidthKey : 1280,
                                        AVVideoHeightKey : 720,
                                        AVVideoProfileLevelKey : AVVideoProfileLevelH264HighAutoLevel] as [String : Any]
```

The key is part of `AVVideoSettings.h`, so is `AVVideoCodecKey`, `AVVideoWidthKey` and `AVVideoHeightKey` however it's unclear to me where to find what keys are supported by `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keys and how they can be constructed are described in  (type AVVideoCodecKey and jump to definition). In your particular case `AVVideoProfileLevelKey : AVVideoProfileLevelH264HighAutoLevel` should be placed in another dictionary and this dictionary should be set to `AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey`:

```
let compressionSettings = [AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264HighAutoLevel]
videoCaptureOutput.videoSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
                                    AVVideoWidthKey : 1280,
                                    AVVideoHeightKey : 720,
                                    AVVideoProfileLevelKey : compressionSettings]
```

Hope this can help anyone

Answer (score 1):

None of your settings are appropriate for `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, which provides you with raw video frames. You're configuring it as though it was encoding the frames to a file. So your settings dictionary should be used with the `AVAssetWriterInput` of an `AVAssetWriter` or set on an `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` with the `setOutputSettings` method.